# Does DateTime.now() automatically get the timezone in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetime

I have a doubt… if I simply use DateTime.now() without specifying any type of time zone, will it automatically use the time zone of the device that opens it anywhere in the world?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just looking at the documentation at the function's source code (By Ctrl+clicking for example) confirms it:

````
  /// Constructs a [DateTime] instance with current date and time in the
  /// local time zone.
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// final now = DateTime.now();
  /// ```
  DateTime.now() : this._now();
````